# Not getting any response in the browser

Tags: node.js, express

This is my client code.

```
var express = require('express');
var url=require('url');
var app =express();
var fs=require('fs');

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.url,req.method);

    next();
});
app.get('/user/data',function(request,response)
{
    response.send("User1,User2");
    response.end();
});

var server=app.listen(7000);
console.log("started");
```

This is my client code that makes a request to the above server. The issue is that the response i.e. "User1,User2" given by the above server is getting displayed in the console but not on the browser.

```
var express=require('express');
var http=require('http');
var app=express();

var body="";
app.get('/data',function(req,res){
    var options=
    {
        'host':'localhost',
        'path':'/user/data',
        'port':'7000'
    }
    var call=function(response)
    {
        response.on('data',function(chunk)
        {
            body+=chunk;
        });
        response.on('end',function()
        {
            console.log(body);
            res.write(body);
        });

    }
    http.request(options,call).end();
});

app.listen(9000);
console.log("started");
```

Comment: Do you need to pass the `res` variable to the `call` function as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
res.write(body);
```

With

```
res.send(body);
```

Or

```
res.write(body);
res.end();
```

Thats not the only issue with that page ) but that's will get you started.

Comment: res.write writes data to output buffer, as buffer fills, its contents being sent to browser and emptied, or you need to command it to send that data to browser.

Comment: thanks !! solved my problem but what is the other issue in the page ??

Comment: try reloading page, your body variable is being appended. or it is expected to be that way?

Comment: move 'var body=""'  inside 'var call' function, so it exists only inside function scope.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use [request](https://github.com/request/request) for this?

If you didn't need the `console.log` in your "client" code, you could have:

```
app.get('/data', function (req, res) {
  var options = {
    'host':'localhost',
    'path':'/user/data',
    'port':'7000'
  }

  request(options).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: do you mean `http.request(options).pipe(res)` ??  i am also not able to understand why the  `res.write(body)`  is not writing into the browser.